# About flex Layout on mat-expansion-panel from angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, flex3

how can I use flex layout in component `mat-expansion-panel` so that it is the size of the mobile screen?

The component:
[component pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk398.png)

how is it shown on mobile view:[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDHLV.png)

you can see the component has been cut in half.

The code:

```html
<ngc-card class="card-custom" fxLayout.xs="column" > 
  <div *ngFor="let inscricao of inscricoes; let p=index" class="container" style="display: flex">
    <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle class="container2" > 
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <button (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">
          <mat-icon  >
            {{ expandedElement !== element ? 'keyboard_arrow_up' : 'keyboard_arrow_down' }}
          </mat-icon>
        </button>
        <mat-panel-title style="font-size:15px">

....
```

Comment: what error you're facing?

Comment: I can't make the component the size of the mobile screen

Comment: show css class `container2` .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.